# What does p:treeTable's rowKey and TreeNode.rowKey stand for?

Tags: primefaces

Both are almost undocumented (most information can be found in the user guide which I checked).

The attribute is documented as

> RowKey should a unique identifier from your data model and used by datatable to find the selected
>   rows. You can either define this key by using the rowKey attribute or by binding a data model
>   which implements org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel.

What I don't understand is:

- There's a `rowKey` attribute on `p:dataTable` and not on `p:treeTable`, but `TreeNode`s which are used to construct the tree table's `root` has a rowKey property.
- Then, there's another property `rowKey` on `org.primefaces.component.api.UITree` which is used

  - once for the value specified in JSF and
  - once as the selection coming from `String selection = params.get(clientId + "_selection");` in `TreeRenderer.decodeSelection` as comma separated list of selected rows

  How can the the rowKey values and the list of selected rows (as comma separated string) which has nothing in common at first sight use the same property?
- When `TreeNode.rowKey` is set to a hashCode of an object (uniqueness assured) it seems to be used as index for array access which predicably ends in

  ```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -307459552
      at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
      at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.findTreeNode(UITree.java:245)
      at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.setRowKey(UITree.java:116)
      at org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTableRenderer.encodeNode(TreeTableRenderer.java:525)
  ```
- `SelectableDataModel` might be involved in the misunderstanding or not, depending whether the above documentation applies to `TreeNode.rowKey` as well or not.

Comment: _Enhancement requests for the documentation seem to be systematically rejected by the devs._ please post substantiated references... I'm curious to these and maybe I can help out. And I have a hard time understanding what exactly you don't understand about the SelectableDataModel. What you describe after that is exactly what it does. It helps in being able to select rows. The rowkey (key for the row in the datatable, do a view-source in the browser and you'll see a data-rowkey as an attribute on the datatable source. It kind of does what converters do to a certain extend for other components.

Comment: @Kukeltje The comment on https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2244 reads like there's generally no interest of improving the documentation unless PRs are provided which is far from ideal. I expanded the use cases of the `rowKey` property which confuse me and added a third use of the property (now as array index) which largely adds to my confusion. Maybe you can shed some light :)

Comment: Regarding the **one** example you posted about the documentation, I have to agree with Thomas Andrasko. I personally did not miss what is requested in this 'issue'. And if it is done for one event it should be done for all. The code-completion in the IDE in combination with what is already in the documentation should be fairly sufficient (I did not hear (m)any others about this. So effectively they say: _"We are willing to add changes/additions to the documenation if someone provides this but we don't think it is necessary and will spend our time on other issues"_

Comment: And if you check the issuelist, you'll  see a [fair amount of changes/improvements in the docs](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+[documentation])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question again and I get the impression you are mixing things up (correct me if I'm wrong).

First thing is that from my experience and the documentation, I don't see the SelectableDataModel being used in the `p:treeTable`, nor is there a rowKey attribute defined on it (checked the 6.1 and 6.2 docs). The quote you posted in your question about the definition is from the **`p:dataTable`**.

There is no need to use the rowKey attribute yourself on the UITree anywhere. It is set internally by the component and used render time to put `data-rowkey` attribute on individual nodes. The values of this attribute will be used again in the selection step. The data-rowkey value of a node is send to the server and there it is decoded to find the corresponding node in the server side tree. The nesting/hierarchy of the model is encoded in the value of the rowkey. E.g. 0_2_1 is the root node (0) then its third child (2) and its second child (1) where _ is the separator. So when you start manually setting this, this whole concepts breaks down resulting in the error you posted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. You're right that I mixed up a lot of things. They all have the same name (which might even be a good idea) for my defense. I suggested a Javadoc for `TreeNode.rowKey` at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3714.

Comment: I just realized I got confused after I read [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234548/why-do-value-updates-fail-for-components-below-roots-in-a-ptreetable#comment87803940_50234548) suggesting to use a `rowKey` on `p:treeTable` which doesn't exist. I then used `rowKey` on `TreeNode`s which increased the confusion.

Comment: Sorry for being part of the confusion. Rowkey is indeed not relevant for the treetable.